# Excel VBA - Copy Rows to new Sheet in different column

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am using the following VBA to copy under a certain condition the Rows from one Sheet to another. I've now a new Excel where I want to reuse this, however this time I would like to start the pasting at column C5 rather than A5. I know that you can specify .cells but this is not working here that simple as I had imagined.

Any help would be great :)

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim Zeile As Long
Dim ZeileMax As Long
Dim n As Long

Set RAW = Worksheets("RAWdata")
Set Closed = Worksheets("RAWclosed")

With RAW
ZeileMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
n = 5

For Zeile = 2 To ZeileMax

If .Cells(Zeile, 5).Value = "Closed" Then

.Rows(Zeile).Copy Destination:=Closed.Rows(n)
n = n + 1

End If
Next Zeile
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot paste a full row's copy into a destination that is less than a full row. Only copy what is data and paste into the top-left cell of the destination.

```
For Zeile = 2 To ZeileMax

    If .Cells(Zeile, 5).Value = "Closed" Then

        .Range(.cells(Zeile, "A"), .cells(Zeile, .columns.count).end(xltoleft)).Copy _
             Destination:=Closed.cells(n, "C")
        n = n + 1

    End If

Next Zeile
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer, works like a charm.