# trying to copy row from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to make a macro to pull all of the data from a specific row on my sales quote template workbook and then make it paste into the next available row on my quote logger workbook but im really struggling to find the right code to make it work. ive searched around but found nothing concrete that I could use.

what I have so far is below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = "..............RAYOTEC LOGGER.xlsm"

For i = 2 To sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    If sht1.Range("M" & i).Value = "No" Then
        sht1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Cut sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This question has been asked so many times that your answer in in [the question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892211/excel-vba-copy-rows-to-new-sheet-in-different-column) in [tag:excel] immediately before you.

Answer (score 3):

Change the part of your code before FOR loop with this,

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("..............RAYOTEC LOGGER.xlsm")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: I was just about to comment that a worksheet is not a workbook and vice versa.

Comment: ... oh, and worksheet objects are not text strings. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the below for the rest of the code as it just takes the values easily and deletes the row data that you do not need.

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet 
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i, n As Long
Dim iMx, nMx As Long

iMx = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row  

For i = 2 To iMx

    nMx = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If sht1.Range("M" & i).Value = "No" Then
        sht2.Range("A" & nMx + 1).EntireRow.Value = sht1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Value
        sht1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        i = i - 1
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: @Our Man in Bananas Hi Thanks for correcting my code format from text. Please could you advise what should I do next time to avoid it. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: no worries... just select all the code you want formatted and click the `{}` button

Comment: Wow my bad now only noticed that button. Thanks Buddy.